# Core Data: display only objectatindex entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a table view controller that displays all `fetchresults` for an entity. when a `row is selected`, I want that row to pass its information to a detail view controller. problem is I get `stuck on how to only show the entity selected` and not all of them before I segue.I thought with just what I had in `didSelectAtIndexPath` it should be changing the textfield's text in the next view controller, but it doesnt. Am I missing something? here is what I have so far.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Athlete *athlete = (Athlete *)[athleteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    AthleteDetail *athleteDetail= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"showAthlete"];
    athleteDetail.firstDetailTextField.text = athlete.first;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:athleteDetail animated:YES];
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
            if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showAthlete"]){
            //prepare

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableView has `- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow` method. Use it to get index of selected row.

You'll have sth like:

```
 NSIndexPath *index = [self.yourTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
 NSUInteger currentRow = [index row];
 YourDataObject * d = // take out data from your model using currentRow

 YourDetailViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
 // pass your data to detailViewController
 [vc setData:d];
```

Comment: would I create a pointer with that? sorry im new to core data. just started today. I appreciate your help.

Comment: By having current row you'll have to set needed data to DetailController by fetching data from your model

Comment: why would I use this vs didSelectAtRowIndexPath?

Comment: No-no. `didSelectAtRowIndexPath` pushes detailController. And after that you need to prepare your detail controller in `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: oh I understand. could you exemplify just a little bit more to push me in the right direction? almost there, really thank you :)

Comment: Added addditional steps for setting data. Hope that helps